# Book about a boy thats transported into a medieval fantasy computer game

Tags: story-identification, novel, books

This is a long shot but I'm really in need of help for this because it was an amazing book. It was either a kid's or YA book. A guess from what year it was published would be 90s-mid 2000s, as I read it around 2008-2011.

- The book cover was in first person view, with the main character holding a weapon, and was a 3D rendered image inside a dungeon or cave (that was very reminiscent of early 90s CGI animation), though there may be variants.
- It would have been set around when computer games were mainstream (maybe around the same time as when it might've been published) It's about a teenage boy who is bored at home, so he looks through an old family computer to play a game and finds one that he has never seen before. When he plays it he gets transported into the game which is a fantasy-medieval setting.
- All that I can remember about the game and story is that the main character is on a quest, he rides horses a lot, (to the point where he can ride horses perfectly in real life), at one point he eats food at an ingame tavern/restaurant? and he tosses the ingame coin currency at the server because he's in a hurry, (don't know why I remember that bit specifically haha), and he meets a gnome/dwarf character who is helping him on his journey, who has a home in an ingame mountain, and that time goes faster in the game. (For example, if he spent 5 minutes in the real world, 3 in-game days would have passed)
- Sometimes as he's playing something stops him from being able the play the game for a few weeks, maybe a concerned parent because he's playing too much or there's a family vacation. I remember during the time when he's not playing the game he's on a farm and knew how to ride the horses there.
- There was a character in the real world who was the main character's sibling, relative or friend. They were like a rival and was also very whiny (to some extent). They were on the farm as well with him and questioned how the main character knew how to ride a horse when he had never done it in real life.

  This is all I can remember but if you need more specific information I can try and answer.
  It is definitely not Space Demons or Demons Don't Dream.
  If anyone knows anything remotely similar please mention it, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!!

Comment: Heir Apparent (Vivian Vande Velde) fits *some* of this.

Comment: It sounds interesting, i'll check it out thanks!!

Comment: "The Queen-Seekers" by Eirlys Hunter might be a possibility.

Comment: @Ayshe I completely forgot about this post, but I think that might be it. The cover is exactly the same as I remember it, thank you so much!! I'll try my best to get my hands on it.

Comment: Oh, cool! I was hesitant to post about it, since I couldn't anything online to confirm the details you listed. If it turns out to be the book, can you post it as answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this cover look familiar?  This is the cover of [*The Queen-Seekers*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3850461-the-queen-seekers) (2000); book 1 of the [Finn's Quest](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?165380) series by Eirlys Hunter.  It appears to be a first-person view through a rocky tunnel, apparently a dungeon, with torches and the hand of the viewpoint character in the foreground holding a staff or wand.

[image: Cover of The Queen-Seekers]

The main character, Finn, starts to play a computer game called "The Ultimate Adventure" and ends up sucked into the computer world where he is sent on a quest in a land called "Coralia."

The back cover blurb reads:

> Finn's life takes on an unreal twist when he finds himself actually in a computer game world. It's a world at war, a world of magic and evil, in which someone wants Finn dead. With Gala, a girl who's addicted to risk-taking, he begins his dangerous but exciting journey through a land where all the rules are different.

The "game" can definitely have effects in the real-world; in the second book, [*Coldkeep Castle*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3850482-coldkeep-castle) (2001) his father is kidnapped into the game and Finn must re-enter the game to rescue him.

Time definitely passed much faster in the game world; the third book [*The Slave-Stealers*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3850485-the-slave-stealers) (2004) takes place a few weeks/months later in the real world, but 4 years have passed in the game world.

I've found a higher-resolution image of the 2nd book's cover; you can definitely see that it appears to be computer-rendered image.  (Complete with a highly-unrealistic hand holding a staff.)

[image: Cover of Coldkeep Castle]

Comment: How did you find this?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It looked like a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/206145/book-about-a-boy-that-enters-a-medieval-fantasy-pc-computer-game, but some of the details hadn't been matched (the cover was wrong) and the answer there was pretty incomplete.  So I did some digging.

Comment: From the querent: 
"I emailed the author of Finn's Quest: The Queen Seekers and i've gotten a physical copy and it is exactly the same book. I can't really tell if its meant for children or not because there is some swearing? But I definitely recommend it if the description interested you. Thank you so much to everyone who helped with this! And to anyone who has read it... How on earth do you get your hands on the sequels??"

Comment: @LouiseL: https://express.google.com/u/0/product/10698693073351988866_2123375474406878287_7695788?utm_source=google_shopping&utm_medium=tu_prop&utm_content=eid-lsjeuxoeqt&gtim=COuv_aHzzPiszAEQx5Sdr5KpveuyARiQvO4HIgNVU0Qo4NXP6AUwrNvVAw&utm_campaign=7695788 for the 2nd book. You might be able to ask Ms. Hunter if she has any copies she'd be willing to sell.

Answer (score 9):

I think that you might be looking for [Eden's Gate](https://cindykoepp.wordpress.com/2017/03/25/book-review-edens-gate/)

Although I have not read this title, the cover matches closely to your description.

[image: Eden's Gate Cover]

Here is the synopsis from Amazon:

> When Gunnar Long is transported into the first fully-immersive virtual
>   MMORPG, he finds himself in a new world filled with magic, mystery and
>   adventure.
>
> No more 9-to-5 job. No more studio apartment. No more reality TV.
>
> Finally, he's in a place where he can call home, a place with people
>   he can call friends.
>
> But as more people want to trade their real world lives to get inside
>   Eden's Gate, the government of the outside world wants the "game" shut
>   down at all costs.
>
> Gunnar must learn to survive, grow in power and find a way to send a
>   message back to his old home.
>
> "We're fine. We're alive. Eden's Gate is real."

Comment: Sorry but i don't think it is, the main character in Eden's Gate seems like he is much older than the one i'm thinking about and I think he is also the only one who knows about his game, but I will definitely check it out, thank you!

Comment: @LouiseL. Ok, thank you for the confirmation. The bounty expires in 3 days, subtract 7 hours or so. I am hoping someone else will answer soon.